# Can I be able to use the latest features of latest Android API if I set the minimum SDK version as 2.3.3?

Tags: java, android

Can I be able to use the latest features of latest Android API if I set the minimum SDK version as 2.3.3?

I am thinking that if I set the minimum SDK version as 2.3(API level as 9) then Can I use the features which are there in the recent API though my target API is Recent(21).

What should be a standard values for: “Minimum Required SDK” , “Target SDK” & “Compile with”

As I am starter to Android development.

Comment: it should be obvious that you **cannot** use methods/classes that was added in API > 9 ... unless you find the library that provides such functionality(and use classes/methods from this library) ...

Comment: Depends on whether [Android Support Library](https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html) is able to port some latest Android features for older Android versions as low as v7 or not. For example Toolbar and AppCompat support for Material Design styles.

Answer (score 0):

You can use latest API methods, but you need to put such a method call in if statement (to protect against calling method in Android 2.3):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 20) {
  Android21Class.call();
}
```

You need to compile this code with version 21, otherwise will get compilation error.